# Max string size of Ethereum Contract ABI

Tags: ethereum, json-rpc, abi, solidity

I am writing code to communicate deployed ethereum contract through JSON-RPC. When I call eth_call, I need to prepare data set for it. Although [this link](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#use-of-dynamic-types) has details but I got a question when I read dynamic sized unicode string part.It says

```
Finally, we encode the data part of the second dynamic argument, "Hello, world!":

0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d 
(number of elements (bytes in this case): 13)
0x48656c6c6f2c20776f726c642100000000000000000000000000000000000000 
("Hello, world!" padded to 32 bytes on the right)
```

If I want to put strings over 32byte, what should I do? Will it be like following?

```
Sample text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur posuere."
Text size: 48 bytes

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030
0x4c6f72656d20697073756d20646f6c6f722073697420616d65742c20636f6e73
0x6563746574757220706f73756572652e00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 0):

Pad the string to multiple of 32 length.

For your case you've 48 bytes, so pad it to 64 bytes.